# how can we search many to many field in django admin search field

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-admin

Here, I have a many to many field define in Django model and I want to search that many to many field in my Django admin search field. As we cannot place many to many field in the 'search_fields=[]' of the customise djangomodelAdmin class.If anyone have the solution please give some suggestions.

Comment: Are you only going to search on a specific attribute of the many-to-many field.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Say we have two models `Item` and `SubItem`:

```
class SubItem(Model):
    name = CharField(max_length=128)

class Item(Model):
    subitems = ManyToManyField(SubItem)
```

We can search on the *name* of related `SubItem` objects, by using double underscores (`__`) in the `search_fields` of the `ModelAdmin`:

```
class ItemAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    search_fields = ['subitems__name']
```

If one thus enters a query, then the search will take place on the *name* of the `SubItem`s, and `Item`s that contain such subitem, will be returned.